# How to mock GetView operation of couchbase .net SDK

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am trying to write unit test for a method which executes a **view** on the couch base server using .NET SDK, but unable to mock the o/p.

**Method :-**

```
  public int CountJsonDocs()
        {
            int savedFiles = 0;
            var viewResult = _couchbaseClient.GetView("GetAllDocs", "GetAllDocuments");
            if (viewResult.TotalRows > 0)
            {
                foreach (var viewRow in viewResult)
                {
                    var jsonData = viewRow.GetItem();
                    savedFiles++;
                }
            }
            return savedFiles;
        }
```

GetView() method returns an object of type IView

Comment: Could you show how _couchbaseClient gets instantiated? Is it an interface type or third-party code provided by Couchbase? In general, most .NET mocking frameworks don't allow mocking of non-virtual methods on concrete classes. There's also a general mocking guideline that goes "don't mock what you don't own" (https://blog.8thlight.com/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html) which might be relevant to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: CouchbaseClient is a class which is part of .NET SDK for Couchbase

Comment: You can use `MsFakes` to handle the cases where `RhinoMocks` can't help.... When I was in the .Net world I'd sometimes use them together...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: without paying for a heavy-duty mocking framework like Typemock's [Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page): **you can't**.

Longer answer:
Most .NET mocking frameworks work by generating subclasses of the stuff you want to mock and overriding/implementing the methods you mock. This combined with C#'s way of handling method overrides (i.e. if you want to override a method you have to explicitly declare it "virtual") results in most mocking frameworks only being able to mock interfaces or virtual methods on concrete classes.

There's a general guideline when mocking stuff that goes "only mock types you own" (or "don't mock what you don't own"). This basically means that it's dangerous to mock third party behaviour as you have no control over it's API or implementation.

How I get around to testing stuff that uses third party libraries goes like this:

- Write a thin wrapper layer around the third party library that you do control that has a clean interface.
- Write a thin integration tests for this wrapper layer that uses **the actual third-party components**
- Let the rest of your depend on your new wrapper interface.
- You can now very easily test your other logic by mocking out the thin interface now.

This way you guarantee that the third party code does what you think it does (and a way to automatically verify your assumptions in the future) AND you're able to properly test your code without relying too heavily on third-party code.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I work in Typemock.

As mentioned before, Typemock Isolator can help you to mock almost everything. For test `CountJsonDocs()` I've mocked couchbase calls, take a look on the example below:

```
[TestMethod, Isolated]
public void TestCount()
{
    //Arrange
    int expSize = 5;

    var fakeClient = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<CouchbaseClient>();
    var fakeIView = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<IView>();
    var fakeIViewRow = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<IViewRow>();

    LinkedList<IViewRow> resultList = new LinkedList<IViewRow>();
    for (int i = 0; i < expSize; i++)
         resultList.AddFirst(fakeIViewRow);

   Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeIView.TotalRows).WillReturn(expSize);
   Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeIView.GetEnumerator()).WillReturn(resultList.GetEnumerator());
   Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeClient.GetView("", "")).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(fakeIView);

   //Act
   var target = new ClassUnderTest();
   var result = target.CountJsonDocs();

   //Assert
   Assert.AreEqual(expSize, result);
```

}

Hope it helps!